# Timestamp Difference and Output

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

In My SQL Database I have a Timestamp Column with values like this one representing the Date of the last edit:

```
2015-01-17 08:55:34.000000
```

I want to compare the Date with the current date and when is the same day I want to echo `Today` and otherwise I want to Display the Date of the last edit:

```
$timefromdb = '2015-01-17 08:55:34.000000'
$edit = strtotime($timefromdb);
if($edit > $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']){echo "Today";}
else{
    echo strftime("on %A, the %d %B %Y", $edit);
}
echo " at ".date('h:i',$edit)
```

It always Displays 01/01/1970. There must be a Problem with `strtotime`. I did a bit of research and it seems like my Timestamp Format isn't a valid one: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Around the web are a lot of Questions about converting Timestamps but I just can't find the right one: I also got a bit confused by all the functions to convert date stuff.

So can someone Tell me how to get a valid Timestamp for using it in strftime and to compare it to the `REQUEST_TIME`.

Thanks in Advance!

**UPDATE: As Always: The Problem sits in Front of the PC. I declared the Variable but never assgined the Timestamp to it :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chop off the `.000000` from the date as it makes the date a format `strtotime()` cannot work with. There's several ways to do this. A simple substr is one of them.

```
$timefromdb = substr('2015-01-17 08:55:34.000000', 0, -7);
```

Comment: The Colum is formated as DateTime in MySql is there a Way to automaticly (or not even add) These Zeros?

Comment: It's actually very odd that it is adding it in the first place as datetime fields don't contain that value.

Comment: When I created the Table I used Timestamp but now I changed it. The Problem must be somethere else. I cannt echo my Variable with the Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly understood you, but
try
1. compare gettype( $edit ) and gettype($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])
2. not sure what $timefromdb will be more then $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], because IMHO when user edited data, time of it action will me less then current time.

Comment: Yeah tryed gettype too and then was wondering why there is no Output. solved^^